# What is this line is in Angular syntax?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Unfortunately I do not understand following syntax. I know what it does, it removes a listener for the listener's array.

```
this._listeners = this._listeners.filter(1 => 1 !== listener);
```

I do not understand this syntax in Angular2 and it is used everywhere.
`1 => 1 !== listener`.

The whole code snippet is

```
subscribe(listener: ListenerCallback): UnsubscribeCallback {
    this._listeners.push(listener);

    return () => { // returns an unsubscribe function
        this._listener = this._listeners.filter(1 => 1 !== listener);
    };
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.filter(listener => 1 !== listener);` ?

Comment: I got this syntax from the book. I typed exactly as it is in the book. Book name ng-book2 page 356

Comment: @echonax i have question on your syntax also. `.filter(listener => 1 !== listener);` What is 1 here? Why we have hard coded 1 in filter. Can you please explain your syntax also.

Comment: ah thanks. you just explained as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a typo in your book.

Assuming it's

```
this._listener = this._listeners.filter(listener => 1 !== listener);
```

This will filter `_listeners` array and

will return any element which is not equal to 1 ( `listener => 1 !== listener` )

That's a short hand syntax for

```
this._listener = this._listeners.filter((listener) =>{ 
    return 1 !== listener
});
```

which is shorter for

```
this._listener = this._listeners.filter((listener) =>{ 
    if(1 !== listener){
      return listener;
    }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It explained best.

Comment: @Sallu Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
1 => 1 !== listener
```

This is ES6 arrow function, [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

For example, `var even = [1,2,3,4].filter(v => v % 2 == 0);` will give your even numbers. Try this in the console of your browser.

And in your question you just need to replace `1 => 1 !== listener`, with `item => item !== listener`.

Comment: I think he is right. I thought you down-voted him due to lack of explanations.

Comment: I dont down vote anyone. I have never down voted anyone :-)  Even if someone is giving me 5 seconds of their time and writing 2 lines I am grateful. Plus I cannot down vote because I dont know enough to judge if answer is right or wrong. I am still learning

Comment: this is arrow function for sure, without any doubt. Don't know who voted down :), but  for example`var even = [1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(v => v % 2 == 0); ` will give your even numbers. I'll update answers with more explanation.

Comment: @anoop thanks for your answer and your valued time. Just echonax answer explained it best. I did one up on your answer so at least it is zero :)

Comment: @anoop can i please ask you another simple question? this new syntax arrow functions, short notations etc is common in all new languages like Swift, angular etc. What is the best way to learn this new syntax. My brain is still stuck in 1999 code syntax.

Comment: @Sallu : there are various articles and websites for new es6 syntax, [like this one](https://codetower.github.io/es6-features/)

Comment: Thanks. Will check.